# How to allow addons on firefox private browsing?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have developed a firefox add-on. It is running fine in normal mode, but it is not running while in private browsing.

Does Firefox support addons in private browsing-mode? If yes, then how can i allow it to work in private-browsing mode?

Comment: That's odd, the default is that it should work in PB. Please share your addon code is it on github?

Comment: is this an add-on made with the add-on sdk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is made using the Add-On SDK, you need to add the line

```
"permissions": {"private-browsing": true},
```

to your `package.json` file. (see also the [private-browsing module in Add-On SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing))

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: @GabrielFair: [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing) say so and jpm version `1.0.7` just behaved that way.